# Перестановка строк матрицы в соответствии с характеристикой

Tags: python, массивы, функции, numpy, матрицы

Дана целочисленная прямоугольная матрица. Определить кол-во столбцов, не содержащих ни одного нулевого элемента (оформить в виде функции). - *сделано*
Характеристикой строки целочисленной матрицы назовем сумму ее положительных четных элементов. Переставляя строки заданной матрицы, расположить их в соответствии с ростом характеристик (оформить в виде процедуры).
Я создаю отдельный массив **xar**, в котором находятся характеристики каждой строки. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом закончить мой способ, для перестановки строк. Либо же прошу подсказать альтернативный способ решения данной задачи.
Мой код:

```
#lab5_var2
import numpy as np
sz = (4, 5)
ar = np.random.randint(-5, 10, size = sz)
print(ar)

def func(ar):
    l = 0
    for i in range(5):
        k = 0
        for j in range(4):
            if ar[j][i] != 0: k += 1
        if k == 4: l += 1
    return(l)
print("Кол-во столбцов, не содержащих ни одного нулевого элемента = ", func(ar))

def proc(ar):
    xar = []
    for i in range(sz[1]-1):
        xar.append(0)
    for i in range(sz[0]):
        for j in range(sz[1]):
            if ar[i,j] % 2 == 0 and ar[i,j] > 0:
                xar[i] += ar[i,j]   
    print(xar)
proc(ar)
```

Comment: Поправил ответ, про xar неправильно сначала прочитал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
sz = (4, 5)
ar = np.random.randint(-5, 10, size = sz)
```

Определить кол-во столбцов, не содержащих ни одного нулевого элемента

```
print(len(ar[np.where(ar.all(axis=1))]))
```

отдельный массив xar, в котором находятся характеристики каждой строки

```
temp = np.where((ar > 0) & ~(ar % 2), 1, 0) * ar
xar = temp.sum(axis=1)
```

Переставляя строки заданной матрицы, расположить их в соответствии с ростом характеристик

```
print(ar[xar.argsort()])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Удивлен, что с помощью данной библиотеки решение настолько короткое)

Comment: она для таких операций и придумана :)